# Python Labeling using dictionary not printing all values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3, python-parser

I am labeling manhole inverts using python and ArcMap 10.3. When I use a dictionary to control the label order some manholes don't print all of the inverts while other manholes do. I can post field information/attribute table info if needed. I suspect its an error on my part using an empty/none field in the dictionary and underlying hash table but I really don't know enough to say that with confidence.

How can I get all the inverts to display? - do a check on every argument for none or "" before inserting into the dictionary?

**Working Label Expression:**

I think here `dict` is set to a list with grouped values `(key,value),(key,value),etc` and everything is working correctly:

```
import json
def FindLabel ( [Elevation] , [Out_Elev] , [Out_Loc] , [In1_Elev] , [In1_Loc] , [In2_Elev] , [In2_Loc] , [In3_Elev] , [In3_Loc]  ):
  dict = ([Out_Elev],[Out_Loc]),([In1_Elev],[In1_Loc]),([In2_Elev],[In2_Loc]),([In3_Elev],[In3_Loc])
  x = json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True)
  return x
```

[image: Inverts Showing]

**Not-Working Label Expressions:**

The next two pictures show where I try to use a dictionary. This first one is changing `dict` from a list to a dictionary using `dict = OrderedDict(dict)` and the second one is setting straight to a dictionary using `dict = {key:value,key:value,etc}`. I don't understand why all 3 inverts display for the manhole at the top of the picture but not for the one on bottom left.

Using `dict = OrderedDict(dict)`

[image: Inverts not showing]

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json
def FindLabel ( [Elevation] , [Out_Elev] , [Out_Loc] , [In1_Elev] , [In1_Loc] , [In2_Elev] , [In2_Loc] , [In3_Elev] , [In3_Loc]  ):
  dict = ([Out_Elev],[Out_Loc]),([In1_Elev],[In1_Loc]),([In2_Elev],[In2_Loc]),([In3_Elev],[In3_Loc])
  dict = OrderedDict(dict)
  x = json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True)
  return x
```

Another code variant where inverts are not showing using `dict = {key:value,key:value,etc}`

[image: Inverts not showing 2]

```
import json
def FindLabel ( [Elevation] , [Out_Elev] , [Out_Loc] , [In1_Elev] , [In1_Loc] , [In2_Elev] , [In2_Loc] , [In3_Elev] , [In3_Loc]  ):
  dict = {[Out_Elev]:[Out_Loc],[In1_Elev]:[In1_Loc],[In2_Elev]:[In2_Loc],[In3_Elev]:[In3_Loc],}
  x = json.dumps(dict, sort_keys=True)
  return x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are accidentally key [clobbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clobbering). In your first example that works in the bottom left, you have a **list** with paired values:

```
332.207435 -> South
332.307435 -> North
332.307435 -> West
```

North and West have the same key value. If you want to put this into a **dictionary**, your key must be unique, otherwise it will just overwrite the value without creating a new key.

Try swapping your [Elev] and [Loc] values in your dictionary:

```
dict = {[Out_Loc]:[Out_Elev],[In1_Loc]:[In1_Elev],[In2_Loc]:[In2_Elev],[In3_Loc]:[In3_Elev],}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by key clobbering, sometimes inverts are the same elevation which is what I have there. But it was the unique key that did the trick. Thank you. Problem now is that I can have multiple inverts in the same direction - not common but possible. Perhaps I can just print the list with pairs instead of worrying about dictionaries.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if lists were working, what was the reason for trying to use dictionaries?

Comment: Probably the main reason is that I hack around on my code snippets till they work. Second, what I was labeling made sense with key:value pairs (invert and direction) and I figured a dictionary was made that for so I used it. In-fact, when i realized the code wasn't printing all inverts on some, I had to work backwards until I figured out that the list would work.